# python -m idlelib could not save outputs in a file

Tags: python, save, multiprocessing

I copied and pasted the following code of [this site](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-multiprocessing-in-python--cms-30281). I am on windows so instead of `IDLE` I use `C:\Users\MyName>python -m idlelib` in `command prompt` and it works fine.

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def square(numbers):

    for x in numbers:
        print('%s squared  is  %s' % (x, x**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [43, 50, 5, 98, 34, 35]

    p = Process(target=square, args=(numbers,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print ("Done")
```

Now I changed the code above to the following code in order to save the outputs in a file.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

with open('outputs/multip.txt', 'w') as f:
    def square(numbers):

        for x in numbers:
            f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n".format(x,'squared  is',x**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [43, 50, 5, 98, 34, 35]

    p = Process(target=square, args=(numbers,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print ("Done")
```

I created a folder `outputs` and when I use `with open('outputs/multip.txt', 'w')` I see the error in comand prompt `Error[2] no such file or directory`.

when I just used `with open('multip.txt', 'w')` it gets `i/o operation on closed file`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

1. For `No such file or directory`:

   ```
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'outputs/multip.txt', 'w')) as ....:
   ```

2.For the error `I/O operation on closed file`:

```
def square(numbers):
     with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'outputs/multip.txt', 'w')) as f:
```

Open the file inside the function and perform the operations on it

Comment: `Error[2] no such file or directory` for both ways

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path as the below.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import sys

def square(numbers):
    pat='C:/Users/esadr21/Desktop/MHT/Models/outputs'
    file_path = os.path.join(pat,'multip.txt')
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        for x in numbers:
            f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n".format(x,'squared  is',x**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [43, 50, 5, 98, 34, 35]

    p = Process(target=square, args=(numbers,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print ("Done")
```